# Multivariable multilinear homogeneous polynomials with co-prime coefficients representing 1

Tags: nt.number-theory

Suppose $F(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is a homogeneous polynomial in $n$ variables of degree $m$, which has degree $1$ in each of the variables. Suppose further that it has integer relatively prime coefficients. Are there necessary and sufficient conditions on $F$ to guarantee that the equation

$$F(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 1$$

has an integer solution?

Comment: A special case of this relates to deciding whether a number field is monogenic (in this case $m=n/(n-1)/2$). This was question 6 in Narkiewicz and answered by [Uchita](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ojm/1200770215), plus given an effective method to check it by [Györy](https://eudml.org/doc/205206). Denis Simons also has a [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019357701800392) for this special case. (This ignores linearity of variables).

Comment: @pavl0 can you please clarify? The papers you are referring to all deal with one variable polynomials.

Comment: they are dealing homogeneous forms in $n-1$ variables of degree $n(n-1)/2$.

Comment: By the way, would linearity imply that $m=n$, as $F(x,\ldots,x)=x^nF(1,\ldots,1)$?

Comment: From the above it follows that $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=ax_1\dots x_n$, where $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. This is because $F(0,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ is homogeneous of degree m with n-1 variables, and still linear in each variable, thus $F(0,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=0$. Therefore, $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=1$ iff $a=\pm 1$.

Comment: No, for example the quadratic form $xy+xz+yz$ is linear in each variable, and still assumes the value $1$ at the point $(1,1,0)$.

Comment: I am most likely mistaken, but shouldn't we have that $F(x+1,y,z)=F(x,y,z)+F(1,y,z)$, where $F(x,y,z)=xy+xz+yz$?

Comment: All I mean is that degree of $F$ in each of the variables is $1$. Sorry for the confusion -- I made the edit to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93876/discussion-between-lenny-fukshansky-and-pavl0).

Comment: Evidently m\leq n. Wlog F depends on all x_i. Let me assume that for all p, F mod p also depends on all x_i (i.e. for all i, F is not of the form P(x_1, ..., x_{i-1}, k x_i, x_{i+1}, ..., x_n) for P integral). Then write F(x_1, ..., x_n) =: x_n G(x_1, ..., x_{n-1}) + H(x_1, ..., x_{n-1}). Note that G is in n-1 variables and of degree m-1 and satisfies the hypothesis of the question. It suffices to find a solution to G(x_1, ..., x_{n-1}) = 1, since then we may simply solve for x_n. Thus by induction we reduce to the case m = 1, i.e. F is affine linear, in which case it is evident.

Comment: I’m too lazy to try to deal with the general case unless it’s strictly necessary (note that some condition is required because e.g. 5x+2 has coprime coefficients but will never represent 1) —- probably having a solution locally everywhere is sufficient, but I haven’t thought about it.

Comment: [Oh! Sorry, 5x+2 isn’t a problem since you of course wrote that it is homogeneous.]

Comment: @alpoge Thank you very much, very helpful remark!